# XCode 5 behavior script generating permission error

Tags: xcode, behavior

This morning I thought I'd spend a few minutes to write an XCode 5 script for Prefereces->behaviors to hide panels to better focus on Code and storyboard.  A few command keys: how long can that take.....

I used AppleScript, and it runs fine from the applescript editor.  I then exported it as a script bundle and hooked it to a behavior within XCode. When I hit the key command, I get the permissions error:

> Failed to launch script /Users/sss/Documents/pers/XCode Scripts/XCodeCodeFocus.scptd: The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied

The AppleScript is very basic: I've tried:

```
activate application "Xcode"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Y" using command down
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "0" using {command down, option down}
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "1" using command down
```

and (without the activate command in case that's causing havoc)

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Y" using command down
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "0" using {command down, option down}
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "1" using command down
```

File permissions on the file are:

> drwxr-xr-x@ 3 sss  staff   102 Oct  4 06:31 XCode Code Focus copy.scptd

The file is in my code directory, but I can't see why that would affect things.

Is this broken in XCode 5, or am I missing something....

many thanks!